# What is the best CMS for a technology user group?

Tags: content-management-system

We're starting a user group and want our own website for it where people can post, register for meetings, etc. What is the best CMS to use? The server we plan to use is Win 2003 Web Server with IIS 6 and SQL 2008, but also has PHP and MySQL installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is highly subjective. You can have a look at http://php.opensourcecms.com/ where you can try almost all of them and decide for yourself.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an easy and quick start, try [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org). For a better (and maybe more complex) product, go with [Drupal](http://drupal.org).